# How strict are luggage restrictions on the Incarail train to Machu Picchu (Aguas Calientes)?

Tags: trains, luggage, peru, machu-picchu

I found on incarail.com website that:

> In addition, that large baggage is not permitted on the train
>   service. We recommend that you take the necessary precautions and
>   carry equipment baggage not exceeding 8 kg (17.6 pounds), and of the
>   same dimensions as permitted airline hand luggage.

How strict those rules are? I'm going to board the train with standard carry-on bag and city-backpack. Does anyone knows if its okay?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I did this two and a half years ago, and took a 75L pack and a day pack.  My friend also had one, and the six others in our group also had backpacks plus odds and ends.  There was no problem.

However, the train was also only half full (October).  I imagine the rules are there so that in the peak season, if it's busy they can then start enforcing them.

So short answer - it depends on when you go, and what staff you get, and how full the train is :)

Answer (score 7):

Never seen a problem with this. I did it once with a large 80L backpack plus one camera bag weighing considerably more than 8kg and once with a rolling 26" suitcase plus an even larger camera bag. No problem in either case. Keep in mind that this is not an official rule but checks tend to be loose on trains compared to airplanes.